# Getting strange characters on webpage after import to new database

Tags: html, mariadb, webserver

I have an old site, and i'm trying to import it to another database. Although whenever I import it on the new database, i'm getting strange characters.

[image]

Which should be:

[image]

Both databases and all the tables are the same type (utf-8-general-ci)

In the header of the site I have the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I have also tried multiple database applications (adminer, phpmyadmin and navicat) which are all exporting them as utf-8

Who can help me with this issue

Comment: It's the same type of database? You've added both MySQL and MariaDB tags.

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well since you have the correct collation then here is your problem:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Should be

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: You forgot a doublequote, but unfortunately that doesn't fix it.

Comment: I didn't solve it? What makes you think that?

Comment: @Timberman oh you only fixed the tags, I thought you fixed the thing. Well could you try using one meta tag for the http-equiv and one for the charset then? I updated the answer.